# How to insert trademark symbol in LabelField on Blackberry

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, symbols, labelfield

I'm trying to figure out how to add a trademark ™ symbol on a LabelField in Blackberry API v5.0. Can anyone please help me?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
add(new LabelField("trademark \u2122 symbol"));
```